# How to set border color to only the curved part of border in a card

Tags: flutter, dart

[This is the card which has to be edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkmJo.png) I have created a card in flutter with RoundedRectangleBorder(with the curves at top right and bottom left positions). Now I want to add border color only to the curves.  How should I do it?

Comment: share requirement image

Comment: yes share the UI that will be easy for us to understand

Comment: first thing, help us to help you by attaching an image

Comment: @sohelyadav I have attached an image with the question, pls check it out.

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ I have attached the image with the question pls check it out.

Comment: @ManasAgrawal does my below answer worked?

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ Sorry man it didn't worked out the way I was hoping, but I found an alternate approach to do it. I really appreciate the effort. Thanks man:)